# JWPlayer 6 Access Controls From Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I need to find a way to access the JwPlayer6's controls through Javascript and click them. For my specific project, I need to click the player's "Share" button through another custom button placed elsewhere on the document.

I'm aware of JwPlayer's API based on how it's detailed here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference .

It does allow to do things like play/pause/seek, however it doesn't seem to provide any means to access controls (custom buttons, share button etc) .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid the dock/share button is not accessible via the API, sorry.